# Qt to gray out and disable all actions in MainWindow

Tags: windows-7, qt4

Say upon launching the Qt application, is there a way to display a grayed out main window, and disable all the widgets (buttons/checkboxes/etc) - not able to click. Once the user open a file or do some init procedure, the main window becomes non-grayed out and enable all widgets. Is this something possible in Qt?

Comment: I think the OP is wondering how to grab all actions and disable them at once, rather than disabling them all individually.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Just call `QWidget::setEnabled(false)` to disable a window/widget, and `QWidget::setEnabled(true)` to enable it. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop

By the way, the Qt documentation is very comprehensive. Just search there, and you should easily find answers to many questions.

Answer (score 0):

In my software, before creating a new widget, I disabled all the buttons in the parent window with this:

```
void MainWindow::disableAllButtons(bool toBeEnabled){    
    QList<QPushButton *> buttonsList = this->findChildren<QPushButton *>();
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonsList.count(); i++){
        buttonsList.at(i)->setEnabled(toBeEnabled);
    }
}
```

Of course I had to call this again, when closing the widget, to re-enable the buttons.
Guess it can be adapted to disable/enable other kind of widgets. It works on QT 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

Add a gray overlay label, those size equals your main window. Of course, don't forget the `setEnabled(false)`.